# hg rename doesn't delete the original folder in the working copy

Tags: mercurial, rename

I've a directory in Mercurial repository called httpdocs/css/ui-lightness. I want to move this directory and all its contents to httpdocs/css/jquery/themes/ui-lightness. So, I think this is the command to launch:

```
hg rename httpdocs/css/ui-lightness httpdocs/css/jquery/themes/ui-lightness
```

In fact, I've already tried and it seems to work, except that in the working copy the "source" directory (that is, httpdocs/css/ui-lightness) is NOT deleted (while in the repository it is).

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Krtek found, what you're doing *should* work.  Here's me running it locally:

```
~$ mkdir -p httpdocs/css/ui-lightness
~$ cd httpdocs/
~/httpdocs$ hg init
~/httpdocs$ echo test > css/ui-lightness/file
~/httpdocs$ hg commit -A -m "initial commit, old location"
adding css/ui-lightness/file
~/httpdocs$ hg rename css/ui-lightness css/jquery/themes/ui-lightness
moving css/ui-lightness/file to css/jquery/themes/ui-lightness/file
~/httpdocs$ ;s
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
~/httpdocs$ ls
css
~/httpdocs$ tree
.
`-- css
    `-- jquery
        `-- themes
            `-- ui-lightness
                `-- file

4 directories, 1 file
~/httpdocs$ hg stat
A css/jquery/themes/ui-lightness/file
R css/ui-lightness/file
```

If you have any untracked (possibly ignored) files in `httpdocs/css/ui-lightness` they won't be renamed and thus the directory won't be empty and thus not removed, but the tracked contents in that directory should be moved.

Notice I've not yet committed that rename (and that it shows up as an Add and a Remove even though Mercurial knows it's a rename), but for it to be reflected in other clones, I'd need to `hg commit`, `hg push` and they'd have to `hg pull` and then either `hg update` or `hg merge`.

Comment: You are right. The directory wasn't deleted because it contains untracked files (ie the boring .DS_Store files)!

Comment: It's almost enough to make you long for the days of the resource fork.  Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

What are you calling the "repository" and the "working copy" and where do you do your `hg rename` command ?

I think you just forgot to push your changes on one side and then do a pull on the other side. Changes won't magically appear in all the clones of your repository, you must retrieve the changes.

I just tested, `hg rename` removes the files just fine.

Answer (score -1):

It does not delete the source, it just marks it for removal in the repository. You should remove files by hands afterwards.

Comment: That's not accurate.  'hg rename' does remove the source.

Comment: Oops, this must be right - as well as `hg remove`, `hg rename` deletes the actual source